# Using TestTools.UnitTesting .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am building a new project with .NET Core using Visual Studio 2015. The project builds and compiles as expected. I tried to to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` the way I would do this with a ASP.NET project would be References->Add Reference etc. Seems I am unable to add it this way with Visual Studio 2015. I found an article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest) that suggests building a project from the CLI. `dotnet new mstest`. However that results in this message on my machine:

```
Specify --help for a list of available options and commands.
Unrecognized command or argument 'mstest'
```

I tried the same command on Ubuntu machine and it creates the project without a problem. 
I am on a Windows machine. 
Any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same on my computer when I try to use `dotnet new mstest` as well as `dotnet new xunit` for `Visual Studio 2015` on Windows 10. I tried `dotnet new mstest` in `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` and it worked fine, though.

I don't know the reason for sure as to why it's not available for 2015, it might be a limitation at this time of the dot net core tooling available for VS 2015 on Windows.

However, the reason I'm posting this as an answer is because I was eventually able to get `mstest` setup with the following workaround:

I had to manually include the following into the `appsettings.json` file of a new `.Net CORE` project that I created through the `Visual Studio 2015` IDE:

```
"testRunner": "mstest",
"dependencies": {
  "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.1.1-preview",
  "MsTest.TestFramework": "1.0.4-preview",
  ...
}
```

After that, `mstest` works for me in that project in VS 2015 and tests are discovered by the `Test Explorer`.